# SQL select result from two fields where equal to same search result

Tags: sql, postgresql

Currently SQL statement as below:

```
SELECT result FROM tableA WHERE
field1 = (SELECT x FROM tableB WHERE field3 = "XXX") OR 
field2 = (SELECT x FROM tableB WHERE field3 = "XXX");
```

Can simplify the two select statement`SELECT x FROM tableB WHERE field3 = "XXX"` ?

Have using JOIN and currently the statement as below:

```
SELECT resultB from tableA a join 
tableB b on 
b.field4 = a.field1 or 
b.field4 = a.field2 where 
b.field3 = "XXX";
```

Further on, "XXX" is from below SQL statement:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(resultA) FROM tableC c WHERE c.field5 is false;
```

How to combine this to having result as below:

```
resultA(1), resultB(1)
resultA(2), resultB(2)
resultA(3), resultB(3)
...
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can join the tables.

```
SELECT
    a.result
FROM tableA a
join tableB b on b.x = a.field1 or b.x = a.field2
where b.field3 = 'XXX'
```

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with `EXISTS`:

```
SELECT a.result 
FROM tableA a
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 
  FROM tableB b 
  WHERE b.field3 = 'XXX' AND b.x IN (a.field1, a.field2)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Although you can "simplify" the logic, if you care about performance that is probably not a good route.  Instead, I would suggest using `exists` twice:

```
SELECT a.result
FROM tableA a
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM tableB b
              WHERE b.x = a.field1 AND b.field3 = 'XXX'
             ) OR 
      EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM tableB b
              WHERE b.x = a.field2 AND b.field3 = 'XXX'
             );
```

This can make use of an index on `tableB(x, field3)`.